# Firebase android get all from table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need some help.
I have a realtime database in firebase. I need to bring all records from this table.
After already setting the connection, I tried the command:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("rlmb-loterias");
```

I need the whole contents of the table and generate an array or a json

[image: example my databe strucure]

Answer (score 0):

first you have to get all the keys and then you can get table values like this :-

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("rlmb-loterias");

usersRef .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                             usersRef.child(snap.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
                                       ValueEventListener() {
                                       @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String data = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                             //enter code here
                    }
                });

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                             //enter code here
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the keys and the corresponding values, you need to attach a listener on your reference. Assuming that the `rlmb-loterias` node **is not** your root node, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference rlmbLoteriasRef = rootRef.child("rlmb-loterias");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, key + " / " + value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
rlmbLoteriasRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

If your `rlmb-loterias` node **is** your root key, then simply attach the listener on the `rootRef`:

```
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```